# Rabbimq listener method ignore @Transactional in nested/called methods and can't use @Lock annotation to ensure isolation in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, rabbitmq

**[UPDATE]**

The code bellow is my Repository class, where I ensure the isolation between concurrent transactions on same entity by using @Lock:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query("select cp from CreateProductSaga cp where cp.sagaId = ?1")
Optional<CreateProductSaga> findOneForUpdate(String sagaId);
```

In other class, inside the commit() method I use the **findOneForUpdate** to get the entity. The @Transactional is needed in the commit() to ensure isolation (@Lock):

```
@Transactional
public void commit(IMessage message) throws EcommerceBusinessLogicException, InterruptedException {
    String sagaId = CommonSaga.getSagaId(message.getData());
    Optional<CreateProductSaga> optional = queryCreateProductSagaRepository.findOneForUpdate(sagaId);
        // other code ...
}
```

Called the **commit()** method in the rest api works correctly, but when I call this method in rabbitmq listener adapter, the findOneForUpdate throws an exception **"javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress"** which means, the @Transactional in method **commit()** was ignored.

The flow from the source to the **commit()** method when called by the message listener (rabbitmq) is:

**1 - The rabbitmq configuration classe, where listener method is defined, in this case is handleMessage in MessageHandler class.**

[image: Rabbimq configuration, listener adapter]

**2 - MessageHandler class, where listener method is defined. This method convert message from the string to the IMessage object, after that, call the callMethod.**

[image: MessageHandler class]

**3 - The callMethod is a switch of methods.**

[image: callMethod (switch of methods)]

**4 - The Facade is an interface of the business (transactional method).**

[image: Facade]

**5 - The commit method is defined here, annotated with @Transactional, and inside it call the findOneForUpdate and exception occur, with message, "no transaction is in progress", which means the @Transactional was ignored**

[image: The transactional method (Where the problem occur!)]

Comment: Show your code. It smells like you most likely have a _self-call_ happening, bypassing the transactional advice.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I updated and detailed the question.